# Django:How to update field value from another model?

Tags: python, django

I want to update the value of field Availability value from "available" to "issued" in the CylinderEntry model when the user Issued that particular cylinder but I was unable to make the change.

here what logic I m executing:

```
class IssueCylinder(models.Model):
    cylinder=models.ForeignKey('CylinderEntry',on_delete=models.CASCADE,unique=True)
    userName=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    issueDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            CylinderEntry.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(Availability=('issued'))

        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.userName+" issued "+self.cylinder.cylinderId
```

here is cylinderentry model:

```
class CylinderEntry(models.Model):
    stachoice=[
    ('fill','Fill'),
    ('empty','empty') 
    ]
    substachoice=[
    ('available','Availabe'), 
    ]
    cylinderId=models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    gasName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cylinderSize=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Status=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=stachoice,default='fill')
    Availability=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=substachoice,default="available")
    EntryDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cylinderDetail',args=[(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cylinderId
```

here is issuecylinder model:

```
class IssueCylinder(models.Model):
    cylinder=models.ForeignKey('CylinderEntry',on_delete=models.CASCADE,unique=True)
    userName=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    issueDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            CylinderEntry.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(Availability=('issued'))

        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.userName+" issued "+self.cylinder.cylinderId
```

help me out make changes in values :)

Answer (score 0):

try adding "issued" choice on your CylinderEntry.substachoice availables

```py
class CylinderEntry(models.Model):
    substachoice = [
        ('available','Availabe'), 
        ('issued','Issued'), 
    ]
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but it is not working:)